# Network simplex method, leaving and entering variables

Tags: network-flow, operations-research, simplex

Could someone give me a hint on this question, which is a past exam question:

> Under what circumstances will an entering variable in the network simplex method be the same as the leaving variable?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible this is a trick question?

The entering basic variable is a nonbasic variable that you increase from $0$, while keeping the other nonbasics constant. Doing this will turn it into a basic variable for the next iteration. The leaving basic variable is determined by the minimum ratio test. This is determined by which basic variable drops to $0$ first, as the entering basic variable is increased. Doing this will convert it into a nonbasic variable for the next iteration.

So, entering is a nonbasic variable, and leaving is a basic variable, and they are converted after the process is complete. By this definition, I'm not sure that the entering and leaving can be the same. There may be a unique situation I am unaware of. I wanted to leave this as a comment but it was far too long. If someone more experienced with linear programming comes along and answers your question more appropriately I'll be happy to remove this.

Comment: Hey Vincent, thanks a lot for the answer. I totally agree with you, as you've said "I'm not sure that the entering and leaving can be the same". So I think the answer could have to do with a capacitated network simplex problem, me and my friend was discussing this. What do you think?

Comment: I'm afraid I am unfamiliar with capacitated network simplex problems. My knowledge on the topic is limited to a grad course I took last fall, Optimization Techniques. A good friend of mine however is currently working on his masters in Optimization Techniques. It's the middle of the night where I am so I can ask him tomorrow and report back if you haven't received an answer by then.

Comment: Sounds awesome if your friend could give us a clear answer to this problem. Cheers!

Comment: I asked, and he said normally if that happens you did something wrong. But, he was sure that their was a unique situation in which it happened, just couldn't remember off the top of his head. I'll let you know if he remembers.

Answer (score 0):

`

> All basic variables are algebraically eliminated before applying
>   optimality check or finding entering basic variables.

` This is done because we want to know if the objective function can be increased by improving values of variables which are kept aside to have a value of zero(i.e non-basic variables).So a basic variable cannot be an entering variable.